# Python Pandas - How to select only the first N rows for each unique value of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame where I need to select no more than 3 rows having a certain value in the column Company:

| Name | Job | Company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jimmy | Driver | Amazon |
| Kate | Driver | Amazon |
| Jhonny | Weiter | Domino's |
| Mark | Manager | Amazon |
| Hugo | Manager | Domino's |
| Carl | Driver | Amazon |
| Jimmy | Manager | Amazon |
| Jimmy | Manager | Domino's |
| Betty | Driver | Amazon |

Which should become:

| Name | Job | Company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jimmy | Driver | Amazon |
| Kate | Driver | Amazon |
| Jhonny | Weiter | Domino's |
| Mark | Manager | Amazon |
| Hugo | Manager | Domino's |
| Jimmy | Manager | Domino's |

I tried with the `.groupby().size()` but I am missing something for sure.

Comment: .groupby('COMPANY').head(3)`

Answer (score 8):

Simply, Option 1:

```
df.groupby('COMPANY').head(3)
```

Option 2:
You could `loop` through all the unique values in the column and print the output:

```
for i in df['COMPANY'].unique():
    x = df[df['COMPANY']==i].head(3)
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe to filter based on specific company:

```
df[df.COMPANY == 'xxxx'].head(3)
```